# Is there a MonoTouch compatible BDD-style testing framework?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, bdd

I am looking for a BDD style testing framework that is compatible with monotouch. Anyone know of one?

I would be grateful if anyone doing  this would let me know, where they have their specs reside.

My thought was to put them in their own monotouch library.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any MonoTouch libraries, but there are some other techniques which might help you. It's possible to write scenarios without using any kind of framework. [Here's an example](http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/source/browse/Example.PetShop.Scenarios/PetRegistrationAndPurchase.cs) of the kind of thing I mean.

The DSL works by having a subclass which provides Steps classes, each of which covers a particular context. I use Screens below that sometimes too, especially when Screens are shared between Steps. The Screens have the actual buttons, textboxes, etc. in them, and are implemented using an automation framework.

Hope this provides something you can start with, anyway. In the event that you do find a BDD framework which is suitable, it's very easy to transition from this to something using real English.

Comment: Thanks, Liz! I shall give that approach a go.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [SpecFlow](http://specflow.org/home.aspx) addin [for MonoDevelop](http://addins.monodevelop.com/Project/Index/4), but it looks like it's only for MD 2.4 and 2.6. It May just be a matter of re-working the plugin to get it to work with MD 2.8. I've tried installing the 2.6 version in 2.8, but  I get some dependency issues. If you decompress the .mpack file for the addin, you can see its contents. It MAY just be a matter of editing the .addin.xml to depend on Core 2.8 and IDe 2.8.

I hope to give this is a try myself sometime soon. I'd really like to be able to use SpecFlow in MonoDevelop and Mono. It's definitely changed my development life in .NET.